# Setting Flash (AS3) variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

How could I set a Flash (Actionscript 3) variable using javascript?
Or is it possible to call a flash function with parameters from javascript?
I have tried  `document.getElementById('flash').SetVariable("data", "asdf");`but it only works in AS2 and AS1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like LiraNuna said, you should use `ExternalInterface` to communicate with flash. Here are the basics:

**Step 1:**
Make a function in flash that sets the variable:

```
function setVar(value) {
    somevar = value;
}
```

**Step 2:**
Use `ExternalInterface` to register the function:

```
var connection = ExternalInterface.addCallback("someFunctionName", null, setVar);
```

**Step 3:**
Call your function from Javascript to set the variable:

```
var mySWF = document.getElementById("swfID");
mySWF.someFunctionName('some_value');
```

If you're using swfobject to embed your swf, another much easier option would be the addVariable method:

```
mySWF.addVariable("var_name", "value");
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work in IE 8. Is this "good browsers only" or am I missing something? Works fine in Saf/Chrome/FF

Answer (score 1):

`SetVariable` is no longer in use on AS3 because of the stricter sand-boxing, but it wasn't completely eliminated, you can still replace

```
SetVariable("varName","value")
```

By

```
FlashVars = "varName=value"
```

And access it via `root.loaderInfo.parameters.varName`.

However, I'd suggest using the new ExternalInterface class instead, read more about it [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface_06.html).

Comment: Personally think you should elaborate more on `ExternalInterface` as it is the preferred method of interactions with Flash + JS.

Comment: @dcneiner: I'd love to, but I don't have much experience with it, so I linked to a good reference instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could look into using faBridge.
Details here:
[link text](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_1.html)